# HTML page not loading when JS is added in WebView Android

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to display the HTML page inside a local WebView and without internet connection but it does not load the content if the script is added in the HTML.
This is the code for displaying the HTML:

```
     String htmlContent = "<html>\n" +
                    "<head>\n" +
                    "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"file:///android_asset/combined_main.css\" /> " +
                    "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"file:///android_asset/libs.css\" />" +
                    "<script type=\"text/javascript\" async src=\"file:///android_asset/MathJax.js\"></script>\n" +
                    "</head>" +
                    "<body>" +
                    content.getContentName() + //My Rest of the HTML content
                    "</body>" +
                    "</html>\n";

            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
         webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);

            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
            webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

 protected class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /**
         * Instantiate the interface and set the context
         */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }
    }


    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            showLoading();

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    view.scrollTo(0, 0);

                }
            }, 500);
            hideLoading();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
//            super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
            handler.proceed();
        }
    }
```

If I remove my JS line, the web page is displayed, otherwise it is not.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the path of your MathJax.js file?

Comment: Inside the src > main > assets folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start your webview using this baseURL:

```
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/"...
```

You don't need to put the path again inside your HTML file

Try with

```
 String htmlContent = "<html>\n" +
                    "<head>\n" +
                    "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"combined_main.css\" /> " +
                    "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"libs.css\" />" +
                    "<script type=\"text/javascript\" async src=\"MathJax.js\"></script>\n" +
                    "</head>" +
                    "<body>" +
                    content.getContentName() + //My Rest of the HTML content
                    "</body>" +
                    "</html>\n";
```